# Como salvar amostras antes e depois de um evento em um buffer circular?

Tags: c, c++, arduino, áudio, dsp

Olá, estou processando um dataset de 17 horas de áudio .wav (16-bit PCM, 192khz), para simular um processamento em "tempo real" que será embarcado em um ESP32, Arduino DUE ou um RASP, depende dos resultados.

**Como estou lidando com isto atualmente?**

Primeiramente eu fatiei este arquivo em amostras de 1 minuto, após eu criei um programa em C que transforma esse arquivo em um .CSV (pulando todo o head do .wav e pegando apenas os campos de data).

*OBS: Escolhi CSV para ter o dado em uma melhor disposição afim de realizar testes no Scilab para validar os algoritmos.*

Com esse arquivo .CSV gerado eu o executo em um segundo programa.
Que abre este arquivo, preenche um buffer circular com 130ms (24900 valores), quando o buffer está preenchido totalmente, o código começa a computar o RMS (Root Mean Square) em janela móvel com sobreposição de 10ms, o tamanho da janela é de 30ms. Quando obtenho um valor superior a 1000 é considerado um evento.

*Abaixo as figuras do meu objetivo:*

[image: Evento de Passagem com demarcação de inicio e fim.]

Aqui fica evidenciado a Janela com 50ms antes e depois a qual me refiro:

[image: Janela co 50ms antes e depois do evento de passagem de 100ms]

**A minha questão que não consigo resolver é:**

Como devo salvar estes 50ms antes e depois do evento, visto que o evento pode ocorrer em qualquer lugar do buffer e se o evento durar por mais de uma janela?

*Alguns dados para facilitar o entendimento:*

```
130ms =  24900 valores do meu arquivo .csv
50ms  =  9600 valores 
30ms  =  5700 valores
10ms  =  1920 valores
```

Já busquei varias fontes, porem a grande parte das bibliografias de DSP e Estruturas de dados tratam estes temas de forma superficial, Apenas exemplificando o que é um buffer circular e não como lidar com ele de forma útil.

Segue meu esboço de código, cujo o qual parece estar com uma abordagem errada do problema mas realmente estou sem ideias de como proceder, no caso criei um dataset de 1 á 100 para facilitar o debug:

```c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<math.h>

    // Define the size of window 50ms
    #define window_size 3 // 30ms
    #define buffer_size 13 // 130ms = 50ms + 30ms + 50ms

    int main()
    {
        //Definindo variaveis.
        int buffer[buffer_size]={0}; // cria buffer com 150ms do buffer;
        int write = 0;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int read = 0;
        int read1 =0;
        int write1 = 0;
        int counter_elements = 0;
        int number_lines = 0;
        int save_line = 0;
        char c;
        char str[1024];     // vetor para armazenar os caracteres lidos como string.
        int inicio = 0, fim = 0;
        //RMS
        int soma_quadrado = 0;
        int rms = 0;
        int pre_amostragem[5] = {0};

        //Define variaveis referentes a leitura do arquivo e manipulacoes do mesmo.
        FILE * fp;
        FILE * LOG;
        FILE * log_rms_final;

        // Open the file and verify is NULL.
        if((fp = fopen("generator.txt","r")) == NULL)
        { // Define o nome do csv para abrir
            printf("Error! Can't open the file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Registra os valores do rms
        LOG = fopen("RMSValues.csv", "a");
        // Cria o arquivo que registra 50ms antes e depois com a passagem.
        log_rms_final = fopen("Log_RMS.csv","a");
        //devemos ler o arquivo e processar:
        int lines = 0;
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fgets(str,1024,fp); //Lê o arquivo de 1024 cacacteres e armazena no vetor str.
            //buffer[write] = (atoi(str) & 0xff00) / 256; // Adiciona no buffer na posição head o caractere convertido.
            buffer[write] = atoi(str);
            write = (write + 1) % buffer_size; // faz ficar "redondo".
            counter_elements++; // Soma um na quantidade de elementos

        c = fgetc(fp);
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", lines);
            //Se o buffer ta cheio.
            if(counter_elements == buffer_size)
            {
                // Janela da passagem
                read1 = read; // read1 carrega o primeiro valor da janela e vai somando um
                for(i = 0; i < window_size; i++)
                {
                    //Faz o quadrado e soma.
                    soma_quadrado += buffer[read1]*buffer[read1];
                    read1 = (read1 + 1) % buffer_size;
                }

                // RMS dado pela raiz da soma dos quadrados sobre o tamanho da janela;
                rms = sqrt(soma_quadrado/window_size);

                fprintf(LOG, "\n %d", rms); // Grava no arquivo

                if(rms > 1000)
                {
                    printf("rms: %d\n",rms);

                    // Salva os 50ms anteriores a passagem e a janela.
                    write1 = write;
                    for(j = 0 ; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        //Torna o preenchimento circular do vetor de pré amostragem.
                        write1 = (write1 + (buffer_size - 1)) % buffer_size;
                        //pré amostragem recebe os valores do buffer referente aos 50 ms anteriors.
                        pre_amostragem[j] = buffer[write1];
                    }

                    fprintf(log_rms_final,"%s","\n");
                    // Grava o vetor de 50ms no arquivo de log no sentido correto.
                    for(j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        fprintf(log_rms_final,"%d - pre \n",pre_amostragem[j]);
                    }

                    fprintf(log_rms_final,"%s","\n");
    /*
                    for(j = 0; j < window_size; j++)
                    {

                        fprintf(log_rms_final,"%d - janela\n",buffer[read1]);
                        read1 = (read1 + 1) % buffer_size;
                    }
    */
                    fprintf(log_rms_final,"%s","\n");

                    //Salva os 50ms pós a passagem.

                    /*
                    fseek(log_rms_final,save_line - 3,save_line);

                    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){

                        fgets(str,1024,fp);
                        fprintf(log_rms_final,"%d - pós \n",atoi(str));

                    }
                    */
                }

                soma_quadrado = 0;
                rms = 0;

                //Faz a cola ficar circular, pula de 160 em 160.
                read = (read + 1) % buffer_size;

                //meu contador deve consumir mais 50ms
                counter_elements = counter_elements - 2;

            }
            soma_quadrado = 0;
            rms = 0;

        }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(LOG);
    fclose(log_rms_final);
    return 0;
    }
```

*Qualquer sugestão será bem vinda. Obrigado.*

Answer (score 1):

Eu carregaria inicialmente um bloco de 2x o tamanho da janela de cada vez, correria a janela sobre o buffer. Depois, carregaria mais 1x a janela. Em pseudocódigo, considerando uma janela de 50 amostras:

```
byte amostras[100]

// carrega 1 janela na primeira metade do buffer
n = fread(arquivo, &amostras[0], 50)
if n < 50:
    exit

// carrega janela na segunda metade do buffer
while fread(arquivo, &amostras[50], 50) == 50:

    // calcula a media movel para cada janela
    // de 0..49 a 49..98 (0 a 50 exclusive)
    for i in 0 to 50:
        calcula_rms(&amostras[i], 50)

    // copia a segunda metade para cima da primeira
    memcpy(&amostras[0], &amostras[50], 50)
```